# Speed with and without 'static'

Tags: c

I know that 'static' is about scope, but I've got a question: what function/variable will be faster to access: a 'static' one or not?
Which code will be faster:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int count;
   for (count=0;count<1000;++count)
      printf("%d\n",count);
   return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   static int count;
   for (count=0;count<1000;++count)
      printf("%d\n",count);
   return 0;
}
```

In my code I'm working with VERY big numbers (with unsigned long long) and I'm accessing and increasing them about 4.000.000 times a second. *This code is not the one I'm working on, it's just an example*.

Comment: As with all performance questions, the answer is "it depends". Use a profiler and find out!

Comment: Both versions have undefined behaviour because of your `printf` so any discussion of performance is irrelevant. You might think I am being flippant here, but I am not. There is absolutely no point whatsoever in discussing performance out of context.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this code is just example. I've said, **this is NOT the code I'm asking about**.

Comment: In addition to what Almo and David Heffernan said and I can only fully support.  Never include print statements inside the code you want to profile.  Even if you fixed your `printf`s, the overhead for the `count` bookkeeping will be absolutely negligible compared to the draconian cost of the `printf` calls.

Comment: @ForceBru: without knowing the context, all anyone can say is code up both versions and run them through a profiler.  I'm going to bet that any difference will not be measurable.

Comment: What @Almo said, plus: in almost all code these days, (a) cache effects utterly dominate overall performance, and (b) your compiler's optimizer is  very likely rewriting your code under the hood anyway.  If your mental model of how your code is going to perform isn't already largely concerned with those two  I'll just go out on a limb and say "everything you think you know about performance is wrong."

Comment: You shouln't worry about the performance difference of your `count` variable being static or not, because `do some calculations` will most likely use much more CPU than the bookkeeping of the `count` variable.

Comment: @ForceBru That's the problem. Advice about this code is pointless and since you won't tell us what the real code is, we can't advise on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a sign of good will, I have made up a program that we can actually reason about.

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
  static const uint64_t a = 1664525UL;
  static const uint64_t c = 1013904223UL;
  static const uint64_t m = (1UL << 31);
  static uint32_t x = 1;
  register unsigned i;
  for (i = 0; i < 1000000000U; ++i)
    x = (a * x + c) % m;
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

It will simply compute the one billionth element of a pseudo random sequence returned by a simple linear congruential generator.  We have to do something more difficult than simply increment a counter or the compiler will optimize the entire loop out of existence.

Here is how I have compiled (GCC 4.9.1 on x86_64 GNU/Linux):

```
$ gcc -o non-static -Dstatic= -Wall -O3 main.c
$ gcc -o static               -Wall -O3 main.c
```

To get the version without `static`, we simply `#define` it away on the compiler command line.

Running both programs took 2.36 seconds meaning there is no measurable performance difference.

To find out why, I like to look at the assembly code.

```
$ gcc -S -o non-static.s -Dstatic= -Wall -O3 main.c
$ gcc -S -o static.s               -Wall -O3 main.c
```

We find that GCC generated identical machine code for the inner loop and moved the special treatment for the `static` variables out of the loop, which is what we should have expected from a good compiler.

Relevant code with `static`:

```asm
main:
.LFB11:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    x.2266(%rip), %esi
    movl    $1000000000, %eax
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L2:                                 # BEGIN LOOP
    imull   $1664525, %esi, %esi
    addl    $1013904223, %esi
    andl    $2147483647, %esi
    subl    $1, %eax
    jne .L2                          # END LOOP
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    %esi, x.2266(%rip)
    call    printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
```

and without:

```asm
main:
.LFB11:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $1000000000, %eax
    movl    $1, %esi
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L2:                                 # BEGIN LOOP
    imull   $1664525, %esi, %esi
    addl    $1013904223, %esi
    andl    $2147483647, %esi
    subl    $1, %eax
    jne .L2                          # END LOOP
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
```

This just re-emphasizes what many have tried to express in their comments: We need actual code to reason about performance and we should really benchmark it while doing so.

Also, you shouldn't worry too much about such things and trust your compiler most of the time.  Focus on writing readable and maintainable code and only fiddle with the dirty details if you have evidence that it is necessary to achieve the required performance.  In your particular example, I cannot see any valid reason to declare the local variables `static`.  It disturbs me as a reader and should not be done.